# Are there a way to log all python stdout and stder in a file?

Tags: python

I'm writing a python program that will run in a container, I'm sharing a directory with this container to save all logs. But I can't redirect the output.

Are there a way inside the python code to redirect all output to file?

Python 2.7

Comment: What do you want to redirect? Can you modify the code? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can replace `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` with any file-like object. You can also `os.dup2()` file descriptors 1 and 2 for a "stronger" redirection.

Comment: It's just to development.

Comment: Yes, it's my own code! But I need to test and  track the logs without enter the container.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just for some development testing, this should work ok.

```
>>> import sys
>>> f = open("/tmp/stdout", "w")
>>> sys.stdout = f
>>> print "Hello"
>>> print "Whoa"

> cat /tmp/stdout
Hello
Whoa
```

You may want to periodically call `sys.stdout.flush()` to get more real-time output.

You could also use a wrapper like this (stolen from [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering)):

```
class Unbuffered(object):
   def __init__(self, stream):
       self.stream = stream
   def write(self, data):
       self.stream.write(data)
       self.stream.flush()
   def __getattr__(self, attr):
       return getattr(self.stream, attr)
```

Then you would do

```
sys.stdout = Unbuffered(open("/tmp/stdout", "w"))
print "foo"
print "bar"
```

if you need sys.stdout back, you should be able to do

```
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Comment: Or just `print >>f, "Hello"` instead of changing `sys.stdout`.

Comment: @VincentSavard I was going to suggest that, but figured the OP has a bunch of print statements that they don't want to change all over the place.

Comment: It's possible, though in this case I'd probably suggest redirecting the output with the help of his shell, e.g. `python foo.py > log.txt`. The question could benefit from additional information.

Comment: I tried it, but it write all the output just after the execution, and I want to track log on the fly.

Comment: @VincentSavard That is also true, but I took the statement "But I can't redirect the output." to mean the OP couldn't redirect like that.

Comment: To disable buffering, it's enough to pass `buffering=0` to `open()`, no need for wrappers

Answer (score 1):

You can give a file handle to `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` to redirect the output or errors to a file.

For example:

```
stdo=sys.stdout
# need a file handle with write mode
fhandle=open("out.txt",'w');
sys.stdout=fhandle

print "I'm the output~"
......
# reset the standard output
sys.stdout=stdo
```

Comment: #platinhom I tried it, but it write all the output just after the execution, and I want to track log on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both at the same time you can do this

```
class OutputLogger(object):
    def __init__(self, output_file='/tmp/output_file.txt'):
        self.std = sys.stdout
        self.outfile = open(output_file, 'w')
    def write(self, message):
        self.std.write(message)
        self.outfile.write(message)
    def flush(self):
        self.outfile.flush()
        self.std.flush()
```

And use it like

```
import sys
sys.stdout = OutputLogger(path_to_file)
print 'Hello Logger'
```